# How do I add a new owner to my AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-accounts

How do I add a new superuser to my AWS account? I need this new user to have all the same privileges to manage AWS as the owner (me)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you can only maintain one set of root account credentials with one owner per account. Even if this is an account you maintain yourself, [Amazon recommends](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/IAMBestPractices.html) creating an IAM user for yourself with administrative privileges to keep the root account credentials secure.

In order to add a user with the same privileges, from your root account you can create that user in the IAM console and grant the user Administrator access with the full-admins policy below.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

To allow the user to access the Account Activity and Billing section, you need to activate the pages in the "IAM user access to the AWS" section on the [Manage Your Account Page](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/manageYourAccount) from your root account.

That should give the user the same level of access as the account owner without passing out the root credentials.